# jQuery slideToggle class with dynamically created id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide / show comment replies.

I tried a few methods but couldn't get class with dynamic `ids`.

My html structure is like this :

```html
<div class="display-comments">  
    <div class="form-group border-bottom" id="comment-1">
        //level - 1
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group border-bottom parentOF-1" id="comment-2">
        //level-2 parentOF-1
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group border-bottom parentOF-2" id="comment-3">
        //level-3 parentOF-2
    </div>
    <div class="form-group border-bottom" id="comment-4">
        //level-4 doesnt have child
        
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried like in the following example with different variations.

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_reply', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var commet-id = $('comment-').val();
  var parentOF = $('parentOF-').val();

  $(this).text() == "show replies" ? $(this).text("show replies") : $(this).text("hide replies");
  $(this).closest('parentOF-').nextUntil('parentOF-').slideToggle(); 
});
```

But couldn't make it work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code assigns variables `commet-id`, `parentOF` but these are nowhere used.

Comment: That is the problem I dont know how to get id :(

Comment: Is your html code dynamically generated?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes and commet-id, parentOF- both generated dynamically is well. see this please http://jsfiddle.net/cwos1yLe/

Comment: parentOF-*  doesnt it mean child of , by example does parentOF-2 is the parent of comment-2 ? ir the inverse

Comment: @SadhilSpring Yes parentOF-1 is the parent of comment-1 and parentOF-2 is the parent of comment-2

Comment: @Dk I have some confusion , if parentOF-2 is parent of comment-2 why it dosn't have show reply button ? I think that's the inverse ? I mean , at first there will be comment-1 then if you clock show reply it'll show comment 2 and comment 2 will show comment 3 ?

Comment: @SadhilSpring parentOF-2 is a reply to comment-2, it doesnt show a button because it doesnt have replies. the button in comment-2 is for parentOF-2. if you click the button in comment-2 will hide parentOF-2. Example : button in comment-1 should hide parentOF-1 and button in comment-2 should hide parentOF-2 and so on.

Comment: Okey , Posted an answer by following your need , please check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Hide At comment `div's` all class that contains `parentOf-` class ,

```
$("div[class*='parentOF-']").hide();
```

then in each button attach event that show child comment on click , otherwise hide child comment and all it's children using recuresive function described in the snippet :

```
function hideRecurssive(id) {
      let $child = $(`.parentOF-${id}`);
      if($child.length>0) {
        var newId = $child.attr("id")
        // get last char that refer to child comment 
        newId = newId.charAt(newId.length - 1);
        $child.slideUp();
        var btn = $child.find(".show_reply");
        if(btn.length)  btn.text("show replies");
        hideRecurssive(newId);
      };
}
```

Here a working snippet as I understand :

```js
$(function($) {
  $("div[class*='parentOF-']").hide();

  $(document).on('click', '.show_reply', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $(this).attr("id");
    
    if( $(this).text() == "show replies" ) {
      
      $(this).text("hide replies")
      let $childComment = $(`.parentOF-${id}`)
      $childComment.slideDown();
      
    } else if($(this).text() === "hide replies") {
    
      hideRecurssive(id);
      $(this).text("show replies")
    }
    
  });
});

function hideRecurssive(id) {
  let $child = $(`.parentOF-${id}`);
  if($child.length>0) {
    var newId = $child.attr("id")
    // get last char that refer to child comment 
    newId = newId.charAt(newId.length - 1);
    $child.slideUp();
    var btn = $child.find(".show_reply");
    if(btn.length)  btn.text("show replies");
    hideRecurssive(newId);
  };
}
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red;
}

.unhide {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="display_comment" class="col-12">
  <div class="form-group border-bottom " id="comment-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"><b>Netmaster</b> said!</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 stimg">
          <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/images/undefined.webp">
            <img src="uploads/images/undefined.jpg" alt="netmaster" class="img-fluid">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 sttext">Google Çeviri, yabancı dili İnternet&amp;amp;#39;teki içerik deryasını tam olarak anlamak için yeterli olmayan kullanıcılar tarafından tercih ediliyor. Bununla birlikte Google Çeviri, her zaman mükemmel t</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 sttime">2021-01-09 02:23:38
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="6">Reply <i class="fas fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button id="6" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-bottom parentOF-6" id="comment-7">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"><b>Netmaster</b> said!</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 stimg">
          <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/images/undefined.webp">
            <img src="uploads/images/undefined.jpg" alt="netmaster" class="img-fluid">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 sttext">Translate aracı halihazırda 100&amp;amp;#39;den fazla dil arasında tercüme yapıyor.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 sttime">2021-01-09 02:23:56
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="7">Reply <i class="fas fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button id="7" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-bottom parentOF-7" id="comment-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"><b>Netmaster</b> said!</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 stimg">
          <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/images/undefined.webp">
            <img src="uploads/images/undefined.jpg" alt="netmaster" class="img-fluid">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 sttext">Google Translate çeviriler için yakın zamana kadar Avrupa Parlamentosu ve Birleşmiş Milletler gibi büyük kuruluşların verilerini kullanıyordu. Çeviriler ayrıca sözlük bilgileri ve kullanıcılar tarafın</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 sttime">2021-01-09 02:24:19
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="8">Reply <i class="fas fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button id="8" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-bottom parentOF-8" id="comment-11">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"><b>Netmaster</b> said!</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 stimg">
          <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/images/undefined.webp">
            <img src="uploads/images/undefined.jpg" alt="netmaster" class="img-fluid">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 sttext">rew rew ew wre</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 sttime">2021-01-09 18:10:46
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="11">Reply <i class="fas fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-bottom " id="comment-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12"><b>Netmaster</b> said!</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 stimg">
          <picture>
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/images/undefined.webp">
            <img src="uploads/images/undefined.jpg" alt="netmaster" class="img-fluid">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 sttext">Google Çeviri nasıl kullanılır? Google Translate anlaşılır bir arayüze sahip ancak keşfedilecek birçok özelliği var.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 sttime">2021-01-09 02:24:43
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="9">Reply <i class="fas fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated as per request. This will allow you to show nested comments and hide them. If you hide a parent comment then all nested comments will be hidden.

N.B. I changed your `parentOF-` to `childOF-` because it didn't make sense. You can just change all incidences of the class name in the code below if you'd like to keep it.

All the code is fully commented.

---

```js
// Add dynamic click event listener
$(document).on('click', '.show_reply', function(e) {

  // Toggle button text
  if ($(this).text() == "show replies") {
    $(this).text("hide replies");
  } else {
    $(this).text("show replies");
  }

  // Get comment-id from parent element
  commentID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

  // Just get id
  commentID = commentID.replace("comment-", "");

  // Store element
  el = $(".childOF-" + commentID);

  // Check if element is visible
  if (el.is(':visible')) {

    // Check for nested comments if hiding
    hideNested(commentID);

    // Hide element
    el.slideUp();

  } else {

    // Show element
    el.slideDown();

  }


});

function hideNested(nestedID) {

  // Find element that is child of the one passed
  nested = $(".childOF-" + nestedID)

  // Check if nested comment exists
  if (nested.length == 0) {

    // Exit function if it does not
    return;

  }

  // Hide comment
  nested.slideUp();

  // Update button text
  nested.find("button.show_reply").text("show replies");

  // Check for further nested comments
  hideNested(nested.attr("id").replace("comment-", ""));


}
```

```css
div[class^='childOF'],
div[class*=' childOF'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-comments">
  <div class="form-group border-bottom" id="comment-1">
    //level - 1
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>


    <div class="form-group border-bottom childOF-1" id="comment-2">
      //level-2 childOF-1
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group border-bottom childOF-2" id="comment-3">
      //level-3 childOF-2
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>

    </div>



    <div class="form-group border-bottom childOF-3" id="comment-4">
      //level-4 childOF-3
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-bottom" id="comment-5">
    //level-5 doesnt have child

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used it as follow but nothing happend, would you please give a complete example ? `if (parentOF != null ) { 
   $(this).text() == "show replies" ? $(this).text("show replies") : $(this).text("hide replies");
   $(this).closest(parentOF).nextUntil(parentOF).slideToggle(); 
  }` Thanks

Comment: Done. I changed `.parentOF-` to `.childOF-` so be careful for that, but otherwise the code is functional for an indefinite number of nested child comments.

Comment: I already accepted other answer , yours will work to I think so upvoting it. thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem didn't see that someone had also answered. Thanks for the upvote.